# Create new PhoneGap project error

Tags: ios, cordova

I try to create project of `PhonaGap` in `iOS` With **PhoneGap 2.3.0**

I Write this line in the termminal (In Bin directory like say here:**[PhoneGap 2.3.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)**)

```
./create ~/Documents/Cordova23/HelloWorld org.apache.cordova.HelloWorld HelloWorld
```

and i get a lot of errors:

```
cp: /Users/apple/Documents/Cordova23/HelloWorld: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/apple/Documents/cordova-2.3.0/cordova-ios/bin/templates/project/: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/apple/Documents/Cordova23/HelloWorld: No such file or directory
```

I hava a long list of error, all say **no such file or directory**,

Why?

Comment: does the directory `/Users/apple/Documents/Cordova23/HelloWorld` exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the directory ~/Documents/Cordova23/HelloWorld before issuing the "create" command.

Type this in your terminal window:

> mkdir -p ~/Documents/Cordova23/HelloWorld

Comment: @Stavash.. i m trying to display text in html file inside www/index.html file but only Cordova logo and Apache Cordova and Device Ready is coming not able to figure out why it is coming..

Comment: Sorry @James, I have no idea what the problem is